# "Insights on" or "Insights into"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> To provide some insights on how to construct the region, we give the following simple example.

Is the usage of `insights on` correct in the above sentence ot it should be `insights into` ?

Please do not hesitate to suggest a better way to express the idea of the above sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely "to provide/give (...) insights **on** and not into. Instead of "to provide some insights on how to" I would prefer to say "to give you some insight on how to...". Note that I use insight as singular, especially since you are giving just one example!

I have one problem with the question though. I cannot imagine the context where one would construct a region. I have a feeling either to construct or region is not the ideal word to use here. If you could clarify this I can improve my answer.

**EDIT** 
So with "characterize the region" it would be:

> To provide some insight on how to characterize the region, we give the following simple example.

*To provide* sounds rather formal to me, whereas the rest is more informal. A consistent formal way would be:

> To provide some insight on how to characterize the region, consider the following example.

An informal example would be:

> To get some insight on how to characterize the region, you may look at the following simple example.

Comment: You can replace "construct the region" with "characterize the region".

Comment: @Michael Paul "Construct the region" would be a natural usage in geometry or topology, or some other branches of mathematics.  It could also be used when defining borders, say in specifying an electoral district.

Comment: "Insight into how to 〜" is much more natural to me, and Google's Ngram viewer suggests it is also significantly more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insight+into+how+to%2Cinsight+on+how+to%2C+insight+about+how+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsight%20into%20how%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsight%20on%20how%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsight%20about%20how%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinsight%20into%20how%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsight%20on%20how%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinsight%20about%20how%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reference](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9ktfZ_oxZ64c.html) from the Canadian Government, to provide an **insight about** something is also possible. **Insight into** is also correct.

Comment: well, in that case I am sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to support the use of "Insights INTO".

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/provide_insight.html

I personally believe this to be the correct application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).